# 'Is true' in maths notation?

Tags: notation

I want to write the following statement in only maths notation without any words:

> $$\sum^n_{r=1}r=0.5n(n+1)$$
>   is true for all positive integers n.

This is what I have got so far.

> $$\sum^n_{r=1}r=0.5n(n+1)$$
>   is true $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}_1  $

Is there any maths  symbols to say 'is true'?

Comment: You probably don't need to write "is true". Just the equality sign and a $\forall n$ will do.

Comment: I don't think it is needed. You can say it in the following matter (using your notation), $$(\forall n\in \mathbb{N_1})\left(\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: $\sum^n_{r=1}r=0.5n(n+1) \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ should be fine.

Comment: Personally I prefer the quantifier before the statepemnt, like user 170039 has it,  but it's a stylistic preference

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "is true". Whenever you make a claim, it is assumed that you mean your own claim is true. I would say for instance "$3$ is greater than $1$" rather than "it is true that $3$ is greater than $1$" or "$3$ is greater than $1$ is a true sentence". In short, Math notation for "it is true that $3$ is greater than $1$" would just be $3>1$

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{r=1}^{n} r = 0.5 \cdot n(n+1)$$

But for some reason mathematicians don't like decimal expressions, so the following would be nicer:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{r=1}^{n} r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Since the comma symbol is used to enumerate qualities, I would use colon which describes rather than enumerate: $$\forall n \epsilon \mathbb N : \sum_{r=1}^ n{r} =\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$n\epsilon \mathbb N \Rightarrow \sum_{r=1}^ n {r} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

This is a complete sentence and does not rely on any previous inferences. In plus it follows the formalism in the sense that any sentence should be structured as hypothesis implies conclusion and any inferences should have been already contextualized.